# CSV Columns to Arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I'm having a hard time dealing with what seems to me to be a simple problem. I'm trying to import a csv and split its columns into arrays that I can run different operations on, then zip() back together.

```
import csv

data = csv.reader(open('test.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=",", quotechar='|')
column1, column2 = [], []

for row in data:
    column1.extend(row[0])
    column2.extend(row[1])

print column1
print column2
```

This code prints two arrays with elements that are individual chars rather than strings. When I try to do this with a single column, column1.extend(row) does what I want.

I'm interested in ways to solve this particular problem or to generalize this to n number of columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change `column1.extend(row[0])` to `column1.append(row[0])` (and the same for column2, clearly).  Extend is for adding the contents of one list to another, append is for adding a single element.  Extend is telling python to treat the string as a list of its chars and append each char.

```
>>> lst = []
>>> lst.extend("foo")
>>> lst
['f', 'o', 'o']
>>> lst.append("foo")
>>> lst
['f', 'o', 'o', 'foo']
```

Answer (score 2):

another option:

```
column1 = [row[0] for row in data]
```

Answer (score 1):

column1 and column2 are **lists**. The method you want to use is *append()* not *extend()*.

Check the official documentation:
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 1):

Each `row` index is a string, so if you want to add it to your columns you either do this:

```
column1.append(row[0])
```

or this:

```
column1.extend([row[0]])
```