# Creating arrays in Python by using excel data sheet

Tags: python

I have an excel file with 234 rows and 5 columns. I want to create an array for each column so that when I can read each column separately in xlrd. Does anyone can help please?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020413/csv-columns-to-arrays-in-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931906/extract-columns-from-excel-using-python

Comment: see the python stdlib [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module..

Comment: Where does the OP say that this is CSV??

Comment: You may be able to convert your Excel document to a Comma Separated Values document and then use the `csv` module which is part of Python's standard library.

Comment: No I have to use it in exactly the same manner as it is in excel but by using python I have to read it and then perform certain other operations on it like I have few customers and their data. I have to report about their missing logs manually right now but I want this to happen automatically by using python.

Answer (score 0):

I might, but as a former user of the excellent `xlrd` package, I really would recommend switching to `pyopenxl`. Quite apart from other benefits, each worksheet has a `columns` attribute that is a list of columns, each column being a list of cells. (There is also a `rows`) attribute.

Converting your code would be relatively painless as long as there isn't too much and it's reasonably well-written. I believe I've never had do do anything other than `pip install pyopenxl` to add it to a virtual environment.

I observe that there's no code in your question, and it's harder (and more time-consuming) to write examples than point out required changes in code, so since you are an `xlrd` user I'm going to assume that you can take it from here. If you need help, edit the question and add your problem code. If you get through to what you want, submit it as an answer and mark it correct.

Suffice to say I recently wrote some code to extract Pandas datasets from UK government health statistics, and `pyopenxl` was amazingly helpful in my investigations and easy to use.

Since it appears from the comments this is not a new question I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
import csv

file = csv.reader(open('file.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=",", quotechar='|')
columns = [[] for x in xrange(5)]

for row in data:
    i = 0
    for col in columns:
       col.append(row[i])
       i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

See the below code, I have added comments wherever necessary.
    import xlrd

```
filename = ''  #give the location of your filename
workRead = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
first_sheet = workRead.sheet_by_index(0) #this will be your first sheet

print first_sheet.nrows, first_sheet.ncols #Print out the rows and cols

fields = {key: [] for key in range(first_sheet.ncols)} #create arrays based on the number of columns

for i in range(first_sheet.ncols):  #here first_sheet.ncols is 5
    for j in range(first_sheet.nrows):
        fields[i].append(first_sheet.cell_value(j, i))

        # fields[0], fields[1], fields[2], fields[3], fields[4] will be your 5 arrays consisting of all the columns value
```